# after executing a back up cmd (via query) how to kill it

Tags: sql-server, backup, rollback, kill

I have a big database (150 GB) that needs a back up and I don't have space in current machine, so I am pointing it to the different box which has space. After executing the cmd, it is executing the query but taking long time, not showing stats also.

Query used:

```
backup database [DBName] to 
disk = '\\Servername\H:\Backup7-7-2017\dbname.bak'
with copy_only, stats = 1

go
```

It is running for more than 5 minutes and no change on stats, and in destination folder the file is not created yet, so I am planning to go for manual backup from GUI. Now I want to kill this running backup as it is in suspended mode, when I checked in activity monitor.

Comment: Have you tried killing the query? `ALT+Break` in SSMS, right-click "kill process" from the activity monitor, or `CTRL+C` in sqlcmd. It probably won't end immediately but just give it a little time. Also I'd say give it more time in general, a backup of a large DB can take some time.

Comment: yes killed thank you, how can i take it again now..

Comment: I suggest you read up on some of the [basic documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/define-a-logical-backup-device-for-a-disk-file-sql-server), however it is doubtful that the GUI is going to yield any performance improvements for the process. You'll need to ask a separate question if you have further concerns. Please mark whichever answer you used as correct to close out this question as well.

Comment: I recommend not using the GUI for backing up a large database. You're likely to have the GUI become non-responsive while the backup runs. You can use the GUI to select backup options, then click the "Script" button at the top to script the `BACKUP` statement to a new window. Cancel out of the GUI, and run the script.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to use a backup path like `\\Servername\H$\Backup7-7-2017\dbname.bak`  .... using a $, not : to access the administrative share. Also, try backing up a smaller database first to make sure your permissions to access and write to that share are sufficient.

Comment: thank you @LowlyDBA and AMtwo , finally i have freed up some space in local disk and taking back up via query .. cool , thanks everyone

Comment: @LowlyDBA i have gone through the above mentioned doc "basic documentation" however i am trying to ad the destination path for that i given the server name under Device name and file name under file option under destination. it is given error saying that "Cant verify the existence of backup file location. Do you want to use the backup file location anyway" - i will create new question for this..

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to kill the backup - exactly the same as you would any query.

- `ALT+Break` in SSMS
- Right-click "kill process" from the activity monitor
- `CTRL+C` in sqlcmd
- and so on...(these seemed most appropriate given the implied knowledge of the asker)

It probably won't end immediately but just give it a little time. Also I'd say give it more time in general, a backup of a large DB can take some time and may not start producing stat updates immediately. Check out previous backup times as a guide if possible.

Answer (score 0):

First, get a session ID with [sp_who2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql), then end the session with [kill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/kill-transact-sql)

```
sp_who2 'active'
kill {SESSION_ID}
```

Comment: killed , but how can i take back up of this

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all find the session from which the backup is running. To
   find that use **Sp_who2** and check for the command column to find
   "Backup...'.

   Now just confirm that it is the same one that you have initiated by
   taking a look at the query fired for corresponding spid.Check this
   by  :

   **DBCC Inputbuffer(SPID);** */Use the spid here/*

   Once you are sure of the SPID just kill the session by using :

   **KILL (SPID)**

   And then wait till it disappears.
2. There will be STOP button next to EXECUTE in SSMS. You can use it to cancel the query execution from ssms.